# We cant display this page right now

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7-emulator, windows-phone-store

When i uploaded and published my app in windows phone dev center i got error as "We can’t display this page right now”. Even when I uploaded the xap file in windows 7 emulator I got the same error. When I posted this error in the windows community I got replay as problem in server connection.

Please help thanks!

Comment: Why was this tagged `Android`?

Comment: This is incredibly vague. Where does this error come up? Is your app a phonegap/cordova application?

Comment: I got this error when i published the app in windows and even in the emulator(sdk 7).my app is phonegap application.